# Write hypothesis for inference rules with proof package

Tags: logic, proof-package

I want to write inference rules like this one: [image] where the hypothesis for C are not stated as a [sequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent) depending on a set of hypothesis but with brackets []. This is as far as I got:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}

\begin{document}
\infer{C}{A \lor B & C & C}
\end{document}
```

How can I put on top of the Cs [A] and [B]

Comment: Please make your code into a minimal compilable document. `\infer` is not a standard command ans is, I am pretty sure, defined by multiple packages. We don't know what code you've got, so any attempt to help you is very likely pointless right now. A proper example will provide people with the information they need to help.

Comment: @cfr well the title says that im using proof package but i get your point and i edited the question

Comment: I don't really see the problem. I wouldn't particularly recommend `proof`, although the code isn't as frightening as the documentation, but it seems to work just the same as with `ebproof`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## EDIT

In response to the new version of your question, `proof` *also* makes it pretty straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\begin{document}
\infer{R}{%
    P \lor Q
    & \deduce{R}{[P]}
    & \deduce{R}{[Q]}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: variable inference syntax]

`ebproof` makes it pretty straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{prooftree}
    \Hypo{P \lor Q}
    \Hypo {[P]}
    \Infer [rule style=no rule] 1 {R}
    \Hypo {[Q]}
    \Infer [rule style=no rule] 1 {R}
    \Infer3{R}
  \end{prooftree}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: non-standard variable inference syntax]